# Remove all child elements from a StackPanel

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have the following xaml code:

```
//some code
<ListBox>
<StackPanel Name="Mess">
</StackPanel>
</ListBox>
```

Then I add elements to `StackPanel`.

But at a given moment I need to remove all child elemnts of `Mess`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 53):

Please try

```
Mess.Children.Clear();
```

Comment: It would be nice if there was more documentation about these options.  I looked at the StackPanel page, clicked on Children, and there was no information about Clear.

Comment: I saved my time, was trying to get around with it.